# WPF - Best "option" for my issue

Tags: c#, wpf

here is what i'm trying to do

I have a function that returns me about 10 values, somewhere between 5 and 15 lets say

Now I want to show every value in the form of a link/button that has a function attached

for example it should give me something like this :

(HTML equivalent)

```
<a onclick="functi0n('value0')">value0</a>
<a onclick="functi0n('valueX')">valueX</a>
<a onclick="functi0n('value9')">value9</a>
```

i gave the HTML equivalent of what I want to do for simplicity, but of course ithas to be WPF

not only am I not sure exactly how to do this in WPF, I also don't know which would be the best "elements" for this

Textblock with Hyperlinks ?
Buttons ?

Thanks a lot for your answers !

Comment: Uhmm what exactly do you want to do?

Answer (score 2):

You should use an [`ItemsControl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Bind its [`ItemsSource` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to something that can access your function. (I presume your function returns something like an [`IEnumerable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/9eekhta0%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).)

Then, specify an [`ItemTemplate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to create the link or button.

We cannot tell you what control to use to represent your items; [weston's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32458344/1430156) makes a good suggestion, but by no means the only viable one.

Answer (score 1):

WPF has a [Hyperlink](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.hyperlink(v=vs.110).aspx)

Functionally it's the same as a Button, the choice is yours to make.